# Keep row of datagridview clicked by user selected

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need the snippet code in C# to mantain selected the row from a `DataGridView` after that row is double clicked.

Right now I'm displaying data from a dataset and the selection mode is `FullRowSelect`.
Any way to set this?

There are two scenarios to deal with:

1. Everytime the timer ticks  the selected row always go to the first row of datagridview.
2. Once a row is clicked, it is selected but after the timer ticks the selected row goes to the first one.

Thanks for your help!

A newbie programmer

Answer (score 1):

You must do it in the function `timer_tick`

```
private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rowIndex;

        if (dgvOrdini.Rows.Count == 0)  //here I check if the dgv is empty
            rowIndex = 0;
        else
        // I save the index of the current row in rowIndex
        rowIndex = this.dgvOrdini.CurrentCell.RowIndex;  

        .......
        .......
        if (dgvOrdini.Rows.Count != 0)  //Now if the dgv is not empty
           //I set my rowIndex
           dgvOrdini.CurrentCell = dgvOrdini.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0];    
    }
```

With this method the selected row will not change.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
First save the index of row selected actually

```
int index = -1 //set the index to negative (because if you have only 1 row in your grid, this is a zero index
if (yourdatagridview.Rows.Count > 0) //if you have rows in datagrid
{
 index = yourdatagridview.SelectedRows[0].Index; //then save index into variable
}
```

now you can update the datagridview...

After update you must set the selecvted row:

```
if (index != -1) //if index == -1 then you don't have rows in your datagrid
{
 yourdatagridview.Rows[index].Selected = true; 
}
```

It's works !

Answer (score 0):

> Right now I'm displaying data from a dataset and the selection mode is `FullRowSelect`. Any way to set this?

The [`DataGridView.SelectionMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionmode.aspx) property will do that for you through the [`DataGridViewSelectionMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c89df86.aspx) enumeration.

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

As for the rest of your question, I think further details are required. What kind of behaviour are you after?

**EDIT #1**

As per your comment:

> After I clicked in a row a new form is opened. The problem is that every time the timer is enabled the populate_DatagridView method is called and the selected row is located in the first row rather that keep selected the row clicked.

One solution could be the following:

```
private _dataGridViewRowSelectedIndex;

private void dataGridview1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    DataGridView dgv = (DataGridview)sender;
    if (dgv.Rows.GetRowState(e.RowIndex) == DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)
        _dataGridViewRowSelectedIndex = e.RowIndex;

    // Open your form here...

    // And when your form returns...
    // Set the selected index like so
    dgv.Rows[_dataGridViewRowSelectedIndex].Selected = true;
}
```

Does this help you out?

Comment: After I clicked in a row a new form is opened. The problem is that every time the timer is enabled the populate_DatagridView method is called and the selected row is located in the first row rather that keep selected the row clicked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but after reading a lot I think I can explain better my problem.  My problem is that everytime I call the populate_datagridview method besides the actualization of the data, the first row of datagrid is selected rather than keep selected the current row or row clicked. Basically, what I need is to update the FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex to current row index.

Comment: That is basically what my code sample does, doesn't it? Is there any major difference? You perhaps got something I don't know about. Thanks for sharing if so. =)